# Extract values from two columns of a dataframe to make a dictionary of keys and values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe containing several columns of data. If there are two columns 'reaction' and 'abundance'. There are multiple times each of these will show such as:

```
    reaction     product abundance 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0  ...  \
0    023Na-a  010020.tot       1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   
1    023Na-a  012023.tot       1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   
2    035Cl-a  010022.tot       0.3775   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   
3    035Cl-a  008018.tot       0.3775   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   
4    037Cl-a  013025.tot       0.1195   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   
..       ...         ...       ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...
```

For every instance of reaction, the abundance will be the same. I would like to create a dictionary of the reaction and abundances:

```
dict = {'023Na-a': 1, 
        '035Cl-a': 0.3775, 
        '037Cl-a': 0.1195}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['023Na-a', '010020.tot', 1, '...'], 
        ['023Na-a', '012023.tot', 1, '...'], 
        ['035Cl-a', '010022.tot', 0.3775, '...'], 
        ['035Cl-a', '008018.tot', 0.3775, '...'], 
        ['037Cl-a', '013025.tot', 0.1195, '...']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reaction', 'product', 'abundance', 'etc'])

df[['reaction', 'abundance']].set_index('reaction').to_dict()['abundance']
```

result

```
{'023Na-a': 1.0, '035Cl-a': 0.3775, '037Cl-a': 0.1195}
```